# Regular expression for url parameter substitution

Tags: php, regex

I've done little with Regex, but I know this has to be simpler than I'm making it.

Given a URL that looks like this:

```
/p1/p2/{p3}/{p4}/.../{pn}
```

where `{p3}`, `{p4}` contain keys to an associate array.

I want to replace the values in the braces with the value in the braces (more specifically, a value in an associative array where this is the key)

So this ultimately becomes

`/p1/p2/p3/p4` and ultimately `/p1/p2/v3/v4`

I suppose I could just replace the `'{}'` with empty, but I want the replacement string to match the contents of the original expression exactly so the lookup in the array works.

I'm using the PHP function `preg_replace`.

`/(\w+)/({\w+})/` doesn't quite work...

Comment: `explode` url by / and replace needed parts?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear (to me), but like u_mulder said, why not use explode and iterate through the array.

Comment: Depends how you're writing to the php file, I'm assuming you're using .htaccess mod_rewrite and PHP handles everything. If this is the case, `parse_url` and use the `$url['query']` to split it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm not sure if I parsed your question right, this might a possible solution:

```
$pattern = "/p1/p2/{p4}/{p5}/foo/bar/baz";
$values = array(
    'p4' => 'eggs',
    'p5' => 'spam',
);

$pattern_fixed = preg_replace_callback("#{(.*?)}#", function ($match) use ($values) {
    return isset($values[$match[1]]) ? $values[$match[1]] : $match[1];
}, $pattern);

var_dump($pattern_fixed);
```

Output:

```
string(28) "/p1/p2/eggs/spam/foo/bar/baz"
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

http://regexr.com?35522

```
$yourNewString = preg_replace("/{(p[0-9]*)}/g", "$1", $yourString);
```

For your "ultimate" solution, I think you would need more than 1 regex to run over the string. A regex is about getting a certain pattern and replacing something with it. Now you are looking to specifically turn several different strings into something else.

I think you're probably better of with a good ol' `str_replace()` or and explode and checking them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you can achieve this **without regex**

```
$str = "/p1/p2/{p4}/{p5}/foo/bar/baz";
$repl = array(
    '{p4}' => 'v3',
    '{p5}' => 'v4',
);

echo str_replace(array_keys($repl), array_values($repl), $str). "\n";
```

Note that str_replace also accepts array as search and replacement parameters.

**OUTPUT:**

```
/p1/p2/v3/v4/foo/bar/baz
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/bSvOes